# How to define log4j default file location

Tags: java, logging, properties, path, log4j

I'm setting up "log4j" logging framework to my java project, and I want to define a default path to the `log4j.appender.X.File=${file.name}`configuration property, if nothing to the `${file.name}` argument has been specified by the comand line.

I need the solution to be **dynamic**:
- when I run the *.jar* file using `-Dfile.name=C:\log\directory\path\log4j-application.log` JVM argument on the comand line **-->** the framework should write to the path that I've specified on the argument;
- when I run the *.jar* file **without** using the JVM argument on the comand line **-->** the framework should write on the *.jar* file path;
Where should I give the default path to make my project understand where it should write the file on?

This is a part of my actual *log4j.properties* file:

```
# Root logger option, use one of the following log levels: INFO, WARN, ERROR, DEBUG, TRACE
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

[...]

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${file.name}
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout=com.webratio.rtx.log.SessionAwarePattern
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=TRACE
```

With the attached settings, the app is working **partly**:
1. `java -Dfile.name=C:\log\directory\path\log4j-application.log -jar C:\Users\martin\Desktop\Projects\Log4j\log4j_example.jar`: including the JVM argument, the *.jar* correctly created the log file inside the already defined JVM argument path;
2. `java -jar C:\Users\martin\Desktop\Projects\Log4j\log4j_example.jar`: excluding the JVM argument, the *.jar* is not able to understand where it should write on, therefore no file has been created;
I was expecting that, on the second attempt, the app could write on the same *.jar* file folder, since the `${file.name}` argument was not defined on the comand line.
That didn't work because it seems that something is missing to assign that "default" path to write on.

I also tried setting `log4j.appender.file.File=${file.name}/log4j.log` on the *log4j.properties* file instead, giving `java -Dfile.name=C:\log\directory\path\ -jar C:\Users\martin\Desktop\Projects\Log4j\log4j_example.jar`as a comand and **excluding** the *log4j.log* name to the path.
Niether this attempt is working for me, since system is raising the following error:

```
[...]
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \log4j.log (Access denied)
[...]
```

This time I was expecting that the framework could write on the same *.jar* file folder, since the `${file.name}` argument was not defined on the comand line and atuomatically get the root of the *.jar* file (*expecting that's the default writing folder*).

I'm using the 1.2.17 log4j version.

Answer (score 0):

#in properties file put like this

log4j.appender.file.File=./history.log